# Script Elements Not Including Files and Empty in FIrebug

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Some of my sites are fine but others I go to create from scratch like so:

```php
<?php
define("NAME", "Terrasoft");
?><!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title><?=NAME?></title>
</head>
<script href="http://yourjavascript.com/8953781221/date.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script href="assets/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {
    $(function() {
        $("#date").html(Date.parse("today"));
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
<style type="text/css">
#date {
    font-weight: bold;
}
</style>
<body>
    <div>
        Welcome to the <strong>Terrasoft Development Server</strong>. This page was output at a system time of <strong><?=date("g:i:s A")?></strong> on <strong><?=date("F j<\s\u\p>S</s\u\p>")?></strong>. The current local time is <span id="date"></span>.
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

... and the `script` elements at the top do not get included and have no content inside Firebug. I am online—that's not the issue. I get `jQuery is not defined`. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Use `src=` in your script tags instead of `href=`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Script tags do not have the `href` attribute, use `src`.

```
<script src="http://yourjavascript.com/8953781221/date.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be aware that `href` attributes are for `<a>` tags/anchor.

the `src` attribute specifies the URL of an external script file.

**Note:** Point to the external script file exactly where the script is written.

Syntax:

`<script src="URL">`